# Get sum of selected/ unselected checkbox values and populate div

Tags: jquery

I have a set of checkboxes inside their respective labels and trying to get the values of selected labels/ checkboxes, add their values and **populate the sum** in a Div underneath.

The **sum will keep changing** depending upon select and unselect of the labels.

I have gotten to the part where the value of each selected label can be fetched on click, added the sum to its DIV and displayed. But here is the tricky part which I havent been able to figure out, how to subtract from that sum when an option is **unselected after it was selected**.

This is the function I have written to generate the labeled inputs from the database.

```
function getLabTestListCheck($color){
        global $db;
        $getLabTestListCheck = $db->prepare("SELECT * from lab_tests WHERE enabled = true ORDER BY test_name ASC");
        $getLabTestListCheck->execute();
        $testType = '';
        if($getLabTestListCheck->rowCount() > 0){
            while($showLabTestListCheck = $getLabTestListCheck->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $id = $showLabTestListCheck['id'];
                $test_name = $showLabTestListCheck['test_name'];
                $test_rate = $showLabTestListCheck['test_rate'];

                $testType .=  "<label id='testType_label' name='test_label_list' class='btn btn-secondary {$color} test_type' data-name='{$test_name}' style='border-radius:0;'>";
                $testType .= "<input type='checkbox' id='test_type_{$test_name}' name='test_name[]' value='{$id},{$test_name},{$test_rate}' data-price='{$test_rate}'autocomplete='off'>{$test_name}";
                $testType .= "</label>";
            }
        return $testType;
        }
    }
```

The above code will generate the labels something like this

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" style="flex-flow: row wrap;" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label id="testType_label_28" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="A.S.O Titter">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_28" name="test_name[]" value="28,A.S.O Titter,200.00" data-price="200.00">A.S.O Titter
    </label>
    <label id="testType_label_1" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="Albumin">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_1" name="test_name[]" value="1,Albumin,100.00" data-price="100.00">Albumin
    </label>
    <label id="testType_label_2" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="ALP">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_2" name="test_name[]" value="2,ALP,100.00" data-price="100.00">ALP
    </label>
    <label id="testType_label_6" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="APTT">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_6" name="test_name[]" value="6,APTT,200.00" data-price="200.00">APTT
    </label>
    <label id="testType_label_7" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="B.S.R">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_7" name="test_name[]" value="7,B.S.R,50.00" data-price="50.00">B.S.R
    </label>
    <label id="testType_label_20" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="B.T+C.T">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_20" name="test_name[]" value="20,B.T+C.T,100.00" data-price="100.00">B.T+C.T
    </label>
    <label id="testType_label_25" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="Calcium">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_25" name="test_name[]" value="25,Calcium,120.00" data-price="120.00">Calcium
    </label>
    <label id="testType_label_8" name="test_label_list" class="btn btn-secondary success test_type" data-name="CBC">
        <input type="checkbox" id="test_type_8" name="test_name[]" value="8,CBC,200.00" data-price="200.00">CBC
    </label>
</div>
```

Below is the div which will contain the (add/subtract on-call) sum of values inside `data-price` attribute

```
<div class='priceDiv'></div>
```

The jQuery I have written is as follows,

```
    // Test Type fetch price from data attr and add to rate list
    var sum = [];
    $('.test_type').on('click', function(){

            var id = $(this).data("id");
            var val = $('#test_type_'+id).data("price");
            sum.push(val);

            var total=0;
            for(var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
                total += sum[i] << 0;
            }
            $('#priceDiv').html(total);
    });
```

I want to subtract the value of **later ... "unselected"** checkbox from the sum.
For now clicking on any label just keeps adding to the sum regardless of selection or unselection

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out myself.
Though it might not be the best solution out there, but it still works so I think I should be fine with it.

Just added a line of code in my jQuery and it worked.

```
// Test Type fetch price from data attr and add to rate list
    var sum = [];
    $('.test_type').on('change', function(){

            var id = $(this).data("id");

            /* Added this if statement to manipulate on class of selected label */
            if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                var val = '-'+$('#test_type_'+id).data("price");
            } else {
                val = $('#test_type_'+id).data("price");
            }
            /* -------------------------------- */

            sum.push(val);

            var total=0;
            for(var i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
                total += sum[i] << 0;
            }
            $('#priceDiv').html(total);
    });
```